# Reading OLE file metadata in python

Tags: python-3.x, ole

I am currently trying to read the OLE metadata in office files using this library (https://www.decalage.info/olefile), however the files chosen (which I'm certain are the correct type) don't seem to be showing up as OLE based files using the test below - I'm unsure why this is as I can't see anything wrong with the code below:

```
import olefile
from oletools import olemeta, olebrowse, oleid
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def get_file():
    file = askopenfilename()
    return file

file = get_file()

with open(file, mode='rb') as file:
    if olefile.isOleFile(file):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Any ideas? If there's a better way of reading the metadata then that would be fine either - I'm not fixed on the library.

Comment: What does "don't seem to be reading properly" mean? It works and gives output, or it does not. Also, are you testing with the right type of file?

Comment: Edited for clarity - whatever file I pick always seems to come out as 'false' - even when I'm sure they're the right type.

Comment: For some reason `askopenfilename` failed for me, but hardcoding `file` with a *confirmed* actual Microsoft Word document returned `true` for me. So, perhaps you tried "whatever file" instead of a real, verifiable Microsoft Office document (`doc`, `ppt`, `xls`, and a few more that [became outdated with the release of Microsoft Office 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Office_filename_extensions)), or your problem lies elsewhere.